# Solve for Rationals $p,q,r$ Satisfying $\frac{2p}{1+2p-p^2}+\frac{2q}{1+2q-q^2}+\frac{2r}{1+2r-r^2}=1$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, rational-numbers, pythagorean-triples

Find all rational solutions $(p,q,r)$ to the Diophantine equation
$$\frac{2p}{1+2p-p^2}+\frac{2q}{1+2q-q^2}+\frac{2r}{1+2r-r^2}=1\,.$$
At least, determine an infinite family of $(p,q,r)\in\mathbb{Q}^3$ satisfying this equation.  If you can also find such an infinite family of $(p,q,r)$ with the additional condition that $0<p,q,r<1+\sqrt{2}$, then it would be of great interest.

This question is related to [Three pythagorean triples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584943/three-pythagorean-triples/1585514?noredirect=1#comment3232278_1585514).

Comment: Do you want an infinite parametrized family, or would you be fine with simply a proof that there are infinitely many solutions? (I can't answer either question, just trying to clarify)

Comment: I already know that there are infinitely many solutions.  Tito Piezas III proved it in the related link.

Answer (score 1):

If you combine the system into a single equation, you find that $r$ satisfies the quadratic equation
\begin{equation*}
r^2-\frac{4(p^2q+p(q^2-4q-1)-q)}{p^2(q^2-1)-4pq-q^2+1}r-1=0
\end{equation*}

For $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, the discriminant must be a rational square, so there must exist $d \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
d^2=(p^2+1)^2q^4-32p^2q^3+(2p^4-32p^3+68p^2+32p+2)q^2+32p^2q+(p^2+1)^2
\end{equation*}

The quartic has a rational solution when $q=0$, and so is birationally equivalent to an elliptic curve.

Using Mordell's method with a symbolic algebra package, we find this elliptic curve to be
\begin{equation*}
V^2=U^3+2(p^4-4p^3+10p^2+4p+1)U^2+(p^2-2p-1)^4U
\end{equation*}
with the reverse transformation
\begin{equation*}
q=\frac{(p^2+1)V+8p^2U}{(p^2+1)^2U+(p^2-2p-1)^4}
\end{equation*}

Numerical experiments suggest that the torsion subgroup of the curve is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z4}$, and we find $(0,0)$ is a point of order $2$, and
$(-(p^2-2p-1)^2, \pm 4p(p^2-2p-1)^2)$ are of order $4$.

These experiments also suggest that the rank of the curves is always at least $1$, and it is not hard to find that $(-(p^2+1)^2, \pm 8p^2(p^2+1)\,)$
are of infinite order.

Taking the negative $V$ value gives
\begin{equation*}
q=\frac{2p(p^2+1)^2}{(p+1)(p-1)(p^4-2p^3+2p^2+2p+1)}
\end{equation*}
and, if we slot this into the quadratic for $r$ we get
\begin{equation*}
r=\frac{(p-1)(p^6-2p^5+7p^4-p^2+2p+1)}{(p+1)(p^6-2p^5-p^4+7p^2+2p+1)}
\end{equation*}

Because there is a point of infinite order, we can generate an infinite number of parametric solutions, though they become increasingly complicated.

Hope this helps, and a Merry Christmas to all.

Comment: If I may add, in general, the special case $$a^2x^4-2bx^3+cx^2+2bx+a^2 = y^2$$ which the cited discriminant belongs to has the parametric solution, $$x =\frac{-2 a^4 - b^2 + a^2 c}{4 a^2 b}$$ from which, of course, one can find an infinite more.

Answer (score 1):

If three rationals $a,b,c$ can be found, these lead to rational $p,q,r$. For simplicity, we'll start with the $a,b,c$. Given the system,

$$a^2+(b+c)^2 = x_1^2\\b^2+(a+c)^2 = x_2^2\\c^2+(a+b)^2 = x_3^2$$

Let $a = m^2-n^2,\;b=2mn-c,$ and it becomes,

$$(m^2+n^2)^2 = x_1^2\\2c^2+2c(m^2-2mn-n^2)+(m^2+n^2)^2 = x_2^2\\2c^2-2c(m^2+2mn-n^2)+(m^2+2mn-n^2)^2 = x_3^2$$

To *simultaneously* make two quadratics of form,

$$a_1x^2+a_2x+\color{blue}{a_3^2} = z_1^2\tag1$$

$$b_1x^2+b_2x+\color{blue}{b_3^2} = z_2^2\tag2$$

into squares is easy since their constant term is already a square. Assume,

$$a_1x^2+a_2x+\color{blue}{a_3^2} = (px+\color{blue}{a_3})^2$$

Expand and solve for $x$, and one finds,

$$x = \frac{a_2-2a_3p}{-a_1+p^2}\tag3$$

Substitute this into $(2)$ and one gets a quartic in $p$ *with a square leading term*. Since it is to be made a square, assume it to have the form,

$$\color{blue}{b_3^2}p^4+c_1p^3+c_2p^2+c_3p+c_4 = (\color{blue}{b_3}p^2+ep+f)^2$$

Expand and collect powers of $p$ to get,

$$d_1p^3+d_2p^2+d_3p+d_4 = 0$$

where the $d_i$ are polynomials in the two unknowns $e,f$. These two unknowns enable $d_1 = d_2 = 0$ to be solved, leaving only the linear eqn,

$$d_3p+d_4 = 0$$

Solve for $p$, substitute into $(3)$, and one gets an $x$ that simultaneously solves $(1)$ and $(2)$. Since one has $a,b,c$, then $p,q,r$ can be recovered using the relations described by the OP [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585514/4781).

For those not yet familiar with elliptic curves, this *tangent method* is easy to understand. It was known way back to Fermat, but has now been incorporated into the modern theory of elliptic curves. An illustrative example can also be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1390422/4781).